# Alternate Row Colors UL LI

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to alternate row colors but instead only the bullet points are alternating colors at http://althedge.xyz  Can someone show me how to do this?
Thanks

I'm using this css code below to alternate the bullet point color but how to alternate the row color.

```
ul:nth-of-type(odd) {  
  color: #ccc;
}
```

**Php file**

```
<?php
// Database Settings 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', '*****');
define('DB_USER', '*****');
define('DB_PASS', '*****');
define('DB_NAME', '*****');

// Connection to Database
$database = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

$sql = 'SELECT * '
        . ' FROM crypto ORDER BY Date DESC, Number DESC';

$resultSet = $database->query($sql);

$currentDate = false;
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate) {
        echo $row['Date'] ;
        $currentDate = $row['Date'];  
    }

    echo '<ul><li>' . 
    '<A HREF="'.  
    $row["Link"].
    '"style="text-decoration: none;"'.
    '">'. 
    $row["Article"].
    '</A>'.
    '</li></ul>';
} 

$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should move the `<ul>` echo outside of the `while` loop. You only want a single `<ul>` element wrapping all of your `<li>`'s. That may honestly be intentional, but thought I should tell you nonetheless.

Next up, your provided CSS is targeting the `<ul>` element itself, rather than the markup inside of them. And, finally, anchor elements have default styling in web browsers – that's why they're blue currently.

```css
ul li:nth-of-type(odd) a {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="http://www.coindesk.com/ether-prices-surge-shadow-bitcoin-dash/" style="text-decoration: none;">dash bubble overshadows ethereum upswing...</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/5xdcv8/asia_is_late_to_the_party_%E4%BA%9A%E6%B4%B2%E6%99%9A%E5%88%B0%E6%99%9A%E4%BC%9A/" style="text-decoration: none;">ethereum rises despite absent eth / cny markets...</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="https://news.vice.com/story/bitcoins-are-more-expensive-than-gold-now-thanks-china" style="text-decoration: none;">is the devalued yuan moving bitcoin...</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://fortune.com/2017/03/03/bitcoin-pricing-record/" style="text-decoration: none;">traders optimistic about the etf...</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, I screwed up and what I really meant was to have the row backgrounds alternate colors..  Sorry... any idea how to do this?   Thanks

Comment: Yup, just change that CSS snippet to:
    
    ul li:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your code, the color is from the `a` tag, you can change your css this way to fix it

```
ul:nth-of-type(odd),
ul:nth-of-type(odd) a {  
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works great except I must have explained it wrong.  I wanted the background color to alternate, not the font.  Any idea how to do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via simple css:

```
ul li {
    color: blue;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The blue color is default link color, you need to change the color for link

```
ul:nth-of-type(odd) a {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Database Settings 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', '*****');
define('DB_USER', '*****');
define('DB_PASS', '*****');
define('DB_NAME', '*****');

// Connection to Database
$database = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

$sql = 'SELECT * '
        . ' FROM crypto ORDER BY Date DESC, Number DESC';

$resultSet = $database->query($sql);

$currentDate = false;
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate) {
        echo $row['Date'] ;
        $currentDate = $row['Date'];  
    }

    echo '<li>' . 
    '<A HREF="'.  
    $row["Link"].
    '"style="text-decoration: none;"'.
    '">'. 
    $row["Article"].
    '</A>'.
    '</li>';
} 
echo "</ul>";
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
?>
```